# mkdir/cp in Mac terminal gives "Permission denied" error

Tags: macos, terminal, permission-denied

I'm trying to copy a directory in terminal from the Downloads directory to a sub-directory within the Applications/ directory, and I keep getting "Permission denied" error. Why is this so?

Comment: Did you try to use `sudo`?

Answer (score 2):

try

`ls -lt`

to see access permission of the folder you want copy file into

then use

`chmod 777 your_folder_name`

to change the access permissions of the folder

Comment: Please don't use `chmod 777` mindlessly, it allows anybody on your computer to read your files!

Comment: take it easy man, what we need to do is solve the access problem, if this solution can solve, why not use it.

Comment: You can solve the access problem without introducing another access problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you "right-click -> Get info" the Applications folder you will notice that the permissions for the Applications folder are Read/Write for 'system' or 'admin'. For 'everyone' it's Read-only. If you are not an admin you need to use 'sudo cp -R Downloads/___Test /Applications'. Obviously, you need to enter a password.

Answer (score 1):

MacOS prevents interaction with downloaded files until you confirm that they are safe.  You can effectively do this programmatically by running:

```
xattr -d com.apple.quarantine ~/Downloads/your_file_here
```

Then you should be able to copy the file.